# Django, better internationalization?

Tags: django, internationalization

Is there a better plugin/app for django than i18n? I mean something with YAML as translation files for example?

Comment: gettext has been around for a *long* time. Perhaps if you mention the specific issues you're having with it then someone can help.

Comment: I got the same question, I mean i dont like _('original text') syntax, really i want to use some keys that are generated by some rules, because in that case translations clashes, plural forms for different languages are hard to maintain, translators don't understand the po file syntax6 so I need to provide em with functional interface that is really hard to build over po file.

Comment: i agree that gettext itself is the issue. just eveything about it is a horrible mess.

Answer (score 2):

you should try django-translation-manager introduced by COEX. It saves the translations into database and generates the .po files. It also has backups of translations and simple admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good alternative to gettext-based i18n in django.  Usability issues with editing can be solved by using [django-rosetta](http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/) or some other tool.  Problem with `.po` files having too much irrelevant changes and therefor hard to merge when using source control has no solution, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can check available options for i18n here [Django Packages - Internationalization](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/i18n/)